# NodeJS download a pdf file

Tags: node.js, http, pdf, download, unirest

Hi i'm trying to download a pdf with nodejs (UNIREST) but i'm a bit stocked.

```
                    var url_pdf = "http://myurl.com/ex.pdf"
                    unirest.get(url_pdf)        
                    .as.binary(function (response) {                        
                       fs.writeFile("./pdf/test.pdf", response.body, 'binary', function (err){
                          if (err) 
                             console.log(err);
                        }); 
                    })
```

When wrting the file, its miss formatted (just a blank pdf file) size is ok.

Comment: any specific reason to use unirest?

Comment: nope, open for proposals :)

Comment: use request module and same code should work fine.